# Numerical methods to solve a Stochastic Differential Equation (SDE) with the noise term inside a nonlinear function.

Tags: stochastic-processes, numerical-methods, dynamical-systems, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I'm trying to computationally solve the following SDE:

$\frac{dx(t)}{dt} = DeterministicTerm - \epsilon \, sin(x(t)-\sigma \eta(t)) $.

Here, $\epsilon$ and $\sigma$ are two parameters, and $\eta(t)$ is a white noise term.

From what I understood, the Euler-Maruyama method can only be used for SDEs of the form:

$dX_t=a(X_t, t)dt+b(X_t, t)dW_t$.

Other methods, such as the Stochastic Runge-Kutta methods and the Milstein method, may share the same "problem".

So, do you know any other stochastic integration method that could be appropriate to solve the previous equation? I studied Stochastic Processes from a theoretical point of view during my Master, but the course wasn't focused on numerical methods. Hence, I don't really now where to search for stochastic integration methods for nonlinear white noise terms.

Comment: What is $\sin(\infty)$? This is more often than not what you get if you apply the sine to white noise.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The sine is defined between 0 and $2 \pi$, so if you get an argument which is greater than $2 \pi$ you can rewrite it as $n \pi + \phi$ and take the sine of $\phi$

Comment: White noise is not defined as function with point-values. What exactly is $\eta$? A piecewise constant function?